# How are "Local Flights" defined in European regulations?

Tags: airport, easa-regulations

Looking at some Greek aerodrome information charts, I discovered that there are airports with the designation "Local flights not permitted". I speculate this is because the areas are near sensitive/military installations.

My **question** is: How is a "local flight" defined?

- Is it a flight where the departure as well as arrival point is the airport in question?
- Is it a request for touch & go?
- Is it a flight around the airport area, beyond what is required for departure/landing (though I wonder how easy is that to define, particularly in case of e.g. meteorological conditions, such as local clouds)?
- All of the above? Something else?

FWIW, I noticed this looking at older charts (suitable only for simulation purposes), so I don't know if this reflects up-to-date information.

Comment: For a EU definition of local flight, see [chapter 1, paragraph 6](https://www.aviationreg.ie/_fileupload/Image/Regulation_EC_1008_2008.pdf): *‘local flight’ means a flight not involving carriage of passengers, mail and/or cargo between different airports or other authorised landing points*, however I've no clue this definition applies to [Greek AIP](https://aisgr.hcaa.gr/aipgr_incl_amdt_0121_wef_28jan2021/cd/AIS/index.html), further analysis is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UK at least a local flight is one that begins and ends at the same aerodrome. This flight could be remaining in the circuit (pattern) or flying a 3 hour navigation exercise a long distance but as long as you come back to the same place without landing away it's a local flight. It is the same in all the other European countries I've flown to, I haven't been to Greece though so there's a chance their definition may be different.

Comment: Is UK still adhering to EU common rules for air matters?

Comment: At this point yes @mins, there haven't been any big changes so far.